# AMD A8 HP laptop loud fan

Tags: system, graphic-drivers, hp, amd

I installed elementary OS on my HP notebook with an AMD A8. My notebook is heating up and the cooler is fired all the time. What can I do to improve it?

Comment: I have the same CPU (and maybe the same laptop , HP Pavilion g7 2269wm is mine .It runs elementary OS) and it is about 55 - 60c idle (quiet) , 65 - 69c (slightly louder) while browsing the internet.When doing extremely intensive work (compiling using all 4 cores , 100% CPU usage) the temperature goes up-to about 90c and the fan is very very loud.I am using kernel 4.4 and TLP installed.These temperatures a good and yours should be like this too

Comment: To check the temperature run `sudo apt-get install xsensors` in terminal and the open Xsensors from applications. Add your CPU temperature to the answer

Comment: Do you have AMD A8-4500m.I have that CPU

Comment: Hi , anyone here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to kernel 4.4 by running

```
cd /tmp
wget \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.6-wily/linux-headers-4.4.6-040406_4.4.6-040406.201603161231_all.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.6-wily/linux-headers-4.4.6-040406-generic_4.4.6-040406.201603161231_i386.deb \
kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.6-wily/linux-image-4.4.6-040406-generic_4.4.6-040406.201603161231_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
```

This will upgrade the kernel to 4.4. Now reboot so you get the new kernel

Then install TLP by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

You may get a black screen on boot sometimes but can be fixed by closing the lid and opening it again

You can also use the power button (press once , do not hold down) to put it to sleep and turn it on again.

Comment: Did this work ?